# Gerar Etiqueta USPS Internacional com o EasyPost C#

Tags: c#, label

Gostaria de gerar uma `label`(*etiqueta*) internacional do `USPS` com o `easypost`, porém quando eu coloco endereço do Brasil ou outro pais que não seja o `US`, ele da erro.

Exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o erro?...

Comment: já consegui arrumar obrigada